# Properties of Unit Tangent Bundle

Tags: differential-geometry

If $(M, g)$ is a Riemannian manifold with or without boundary, its unit tangent bundle $UTM := \{(p, v) \in TM \mid |v|_g = 1\}$ is a smooth, properly embedded codimension-1 submanifold with boundary in $TM$, with $\partial(UTM) = \pi^{-1}(\partial M)$ (where $\pi: UTM \rightarrow M$ is the canonical projection). The unit tangent bundle is connected iff $M$ is connected, and compact iff $M$ is compact.

I need to prove three things:

1. $UTM$ is a smooth, properly embeeded codimension-1 submanifold boundary in $TM$, and $\partial(UTM) = \pi^{-1}(\partial M)$.
2. $UTM$ is connected iff $M$ is connected.
3. $UTM$ is compact iff $M$ is compact.

I got stuck at 1. Here is my attempt so far:
$g: TM \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a smooth function, so $UTM = \{g = 1\}$ is a regular submanifold with codimension-1, i.e. an embedded manifold. However, I am not sure how to show $\partial(UTM) = \pi^{-1}(\partial M)$. Also, if $(p, v) \in \partial(UTM)$, what does it mean? By definition, if $(p, v)$ is a boundary point, then given a tangent vector $X_{(p,v)} \in T_{(p,v)}T_p M$, its "last" component is nonnegative. How does it lead to the fact that $X_{(p,v)} \in \pi^{-1}(\partial M)$?

Comment: 2 is false as stated:  $S^1$ is connected, but $UTS^1$ is disconnected.  2 is true for manifolds of dimension $2$ or more.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Could you please elaborate why $UTS^1$ is disconnected? (edit: +1 and -1, so disconnected?)

Comment: Yes, $TS^1$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}\times S^1$.  Then $UTS^1$ is  isomorphic to $\{\pm 1\}\times S^1$.  The basic problem is that the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}$ is disconnected.